# Restore Transactions in Google In-app Version 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app and its working fine now i want to implement restore transactions method in my app. I did  not find this method now how can i can call or define or make other method to restore transaction in in-app version 3. I searched on net but did not find relevant sol or info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore your transaction using the `getPurchases()` API

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                itemType, continueToken);

 ArrayList mySkus, myPurchases, mySignatures;
 mySkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_INAPP_ITEM_LIST);
 myPurchases = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST);
 mySignatures = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_SIGNATURE_LIST);
```

will list the items that you own and the corresponding data that you can use to verify the purchases.

While you make this call, be sure to

1. Use the Google ID that you used to make the purchase.
2. Not to use the STATIC Product IDs(android.test.purchased, android.test.refunded...). You can use the test-IDs that you created under your IAB test account.
3. Use the appropriate product type and the package name of your app.

Comment: hey, what is mService here?

Comment: It is the instance of the IInAppBillingService(Google Play Inapp Billing Service) that is running on your android device. You would have to create a ServiceConnection between your app and this service to communicate with the Google Play Store.

Comment: These links will help you understand how to establish the service connection and make the API calls.
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

Comment: what is continueToken?

Comment: String containing a continuation token to retrieve the next set of in-app products owned by the user.

Comment: @Siddharth Does it work without internet connection?

Comment: what should be the continueToken value inorder to retrieve a proper result