# Get in Purchased item id which were already purchased in android in app v3?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am new to in app purchase, i am using v3 api, my question is that if i purchase an item from store after that i uninstall the app from device, than i install app again from store, that time i want the list of **Already Purchased** items from play store, means that i want restore the purchased items list, thanks.

i refer http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases

Answer (score 1):

You can restore your transaction using the getPurchases() API

Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655014/832749) helps.

Comment: i did this but i want code on Button's click listener. n thanks, i have demo code but the code that i want it is not present.