# How to restore transaction of In-app purchase version 3 in android?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am integrating in app purchase version 3 in my application. In my application,I want to restore transaction if application uninstall from device and user install again then user should use restore features to restor all transaction which are all ready purhcased.
I want to get the list of transaction done by user. I refer http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-app purchases can be restored using the getPurchases() API.

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                itemType, continueToken);
```

The previous purchases should be listed fine, if you query using proper Package name, Purchase type and Product ID. Be sure to use the Google Account that you used to make the purchase while trying to retrieve.

Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655014/832749) helps