# Android java.io.IOException?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i am using InApp PURCHASE api in m yapplication ,in which i have made an demo project,my project is working but after showing the payement,it is giving me IOExecption at this line here

```
public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {

    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
```

and i am getting this exception here

java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes: 53
please help me for this.,i have not getting any solution till yet....:( :(

Comment: In the verifyPurchase I changed return false to:

    Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;

Comment: @DigveshPatel sir i have used verfify purchase at two place ,where  put this

Comment: hmmmm then say its work or not??

Comment: @DigveshPatel can we continue discussion on chat??

Comment: @DigveshPatel i am getting error in generatePublicKey

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46803/discussion-between-digvesh-patel-and-rajshree)

Comment: @DigveshPatel can we get itemid without paid service???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647508/restore-transactions-in-google-in-app-version-3/17655014#17655014